# How to host a live server on Visual Studio code for people on another network?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

Currently working on creating a website with 5 other people. Is there a way to host the website so they can see the changes?

We are using the following extension's:

> Microsofts Live share
> , Ritwick Dey's Live server

Would it be possible to make it so they can see the website update as the code changes? Do you know of any other tools that offer these features?

Comment: You want the changes to be live? So that every little mistake can break the view for all 5 devs? Read about continues integration / continues deployment and staging environments in software development.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the [Live Share extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/collaboration/live-share) from Vscode is for collaboration in coding.

If you want to host a website without going through a normal website setup process, a simple way is to use [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to temporarily expose one of your computer's port to the public, then ask your collaborators to go to the Ngrok link to access your website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloudflare to expose you localhost , [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xshOfr0Q93c&t=251s)  a video explaining how to set it up.